# dask frame: efficiently drop rows that do not have minimum count of the row's corresponding reference element

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a dataframe of integers with no missing numbers. Due to the size of the problem, I need to find a Dask-based solution that I am unable to for the following problem.

Using the reference value under the column ('ref') and a cut-off k, retain only those rows that have the row's corresponding element at least k times (excluding 'ref' itself). The pandas solution that I have is:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> arr_random = np.random.randint(low=1, high=5, size=(15,7))
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(arr_random, columns=["ref","v1","v2","v3","v4","v5","v6"])
df
    ref  v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6
0     3   3   4   4   4   1   4
1     4   4   1   3   3   4   1
2     3   1   1   4   3   4   4
3     2   1   2   3   2   3   1
4     3   1   2   3   2   1   4
5     2   3   2   1   3   4   1
6     2   1   2   4   4   1   3
7     1   1   3   1   3   1   4
8     2   4   3   3   1   1   3
9     2   1   3   4   1   1   1
10    3   3   1   3   4   1   1
11    4   4   1   1   2   1   3
12    2   2   1   1   2   4   1
13    2   1   2   1   3   2   4
14    4   1   3   3   3   4   2

>>> occ = list()
>>> for i in range(len(ddf)):
...     row = df.iloc[[i]]
...     ref_val = list(row['ref'])[0]
...     occ.append(sum([1 for x in row.isin([ref_val]).values[0].tolist() if x == True]) - 1)
...
>>> df['tot'] = occ
>>> df = df[df['tot'] > 1].drop('tot',axis=1)
>>> df
    ref  v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6
0     3   1   4   3   1   1   3
1     3   3   3   4   1   2   3
2     3   4   3   2   3   1   4
4     4   2   2   3   4   3   4
7     3   4   3   1   4   3   1
8     4   4   3   2   3   4   1
9     1   1   3   2   4   3   1
12    3   3   3   3   4   3   4
14    1   4   2   3   4   1   1
>>>
```

Comment: Hi, although your solution using a for loop with Pandas is probably not optimal, you should be able to use it as is whit Dask map_partitions. Did you tried that?

Comment: Yes, it was way too slow. Sorry for the delay in response. I have slightly modified approach that gave better results that I was able to further tune.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76336493/dask-dataframe-of-strings-works-too-slow-on-row-wise-apply