# Dask DataFrame of strings works too slow on row-wise apply

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I have a Dask dataframe with no missing values. I am trying to apply a function to all but first two columns to do the following:

- col_1 is called R
- col_2 is called A
- col_i (i>2) contains binary strings
- All col_i (i>2) should be translated such that '0' and '1' are replaced by corresponding col_1 and col_2 elements in the row.
- The resulting strings will be evaluated
- col_1 and col_2 are eventually dropped.

Sample input:

```
    R  A   T   U   V
0   R  A  00  10  11
1   R  A  00  10  11
2   R  A  00  10  11
3   R  A  00  10  11
4   R  A  00  10  11
.. .. ..  ..  ..  ..
95  R  A  11  00  00
96  R  A  11  00  00
97  R  A  11  00  00
98  R  A  11  00  00
99  R  A  11  00  00
```

The possible number of strings is very small in col_i (<50), and a simplified version is used below.

Output:

```
     T   U   V
0   rr  ar  aa
1   rr  ar  aa
2   rr  ar  aa
3   rr  ar  aa
4   rr  ar  aa
..  ..  ..  ..
95  aa  rr  rr
96  aa  rr  rr
97  aa  rr  rr
98  aa  rr  rr
99  aa  rr  rr
```

Current code:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, progress
client = Client(n_workers=20, threads_per_worker=1)
client
    
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
    
def score(x):
    return str(x[0] + x[1]).lower()
    
def func(row, i, fs):
    r = row[0]
    a = row[1]
    row[i] = fs(row[i].replace('0',r).replace('1',a))
    return row
   
s1 = ['00']*25 + ['01']*25 + ['10']*25 + ['11']*25
s2 = ['10']*25 + ['11']*25 + ['01']*25 + ['00']*25
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'R':['R']*100, 'A':['A']*100, 'T':s1, 'U':s2, 'V': reversed(s1)})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)
    
meta = dict()
for cn in ddf.columns:
    meta[cn] = 'object'
    
ddf.compute()
for i in range(2,len(ddf.columns)):
    ddf = ddf.apply(func, args=(i,score,), axis=1, meta=meta)
    
ddf = ddf.drop(['R','A'], axis=1)
ddf.compute()
```

Tried using `numba`, etc but did not have success. I would be very grateful for any improvements to the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific example can be vectorized/turned into simpler statements for greater efficiency. However, if the actual code is more complex and the separation of `score` and `func` is necessary, then the main bottleneck is in these lines:

```py
for i in range(2,len(ddf.columns)):
    ddf = ddf.apply(func, args=(i,score,), axis=1, meta=meta)
```

The code above is a bottleneck because operations that could be done in parallel are being done sequentially. Column corresponding to `i=3` cannot be processed until column corresponding to `i=2` has been processed.

A simple way to remove this bottleneck is to put the looping over columns inside the `func`:

```py
from dask.dataframe import from_dict
from pandas import DataFrame, Series


def score(x):
    return str(x[0] + x[1]).lower()


def func(row, fs):
    r = row[0]
    a = row[1]
    new_row = []
    for cell in row[2:]:
        _value = fs(cell.replace("0", r).replace("1", a))
        new_row.append(_value)
    return new_row


s1 = ["00"] * 25 + ["01"] * 25 + ["10"] * 25 + ["11"] * 25
s2 = ["10"] * 25 + ["11"] * 25 + ["01"] * 25 + ["00"] * 25
data = {"R": ["R"] * 100, "A": ["A"] * 100, "T": s1, "U": s2, "V": reversed(s1)}

ddf = from_dict(data, npartitions=10)

meta = DataFrame(columns=[0, 1, 2]).astype(str)
ddf = ddf.apply(func, args=(score,), axis=1).apply(Series, meta=meta)
ddf.compute()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the number of columns is in thousands and rows in tens of millions. I also figured that I can pass columns 1&2 as additional input and use a `dict` to evaluate and avoid replace altogether so as to bypass `score` (or use it to return the values). This improved speed a lot but not for the size of the data. However, I will try again to see if this efficiently vectorizes the dataframe.